# How do I unzip a file in bazel properly if I don't know the contents of the zip?

Tags: bazel

I was to define a rule that unzips a given zip file. However, I don't know the contents of the zip, so I cannot specify `outs` in a genrule, for example. This seems like a common problem, and googling around leads me to people who have encountered similar scenarios, but I haven't yet seen a specific example of how to solve this.

I want something like:

```
genrule(
  name="unzip",
  src="file.zip",
  outs=glob(["**"]), # except you're not allowed to use glob here
  cmd = "unzip $(location file)",
)
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use a [Workspace Rule](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/workspace.html#workspace-rules) to create a `BUILD` file for the zip that globs everything.

Something like this in your `WORKSPACE` file:

```
new_http_archive(
    name = "my_zip",
    url = "http://example.com/my_zip.zip",
    build_file_content = """
        filegroup(
            name = "srcs",
            srcs = glob(["*"]),
            visibility = ["//visibility:public"]
        )
    """
)
```

Then from a `BUILD` file you can reference this as an input using `@my_zip//:srcs`

Comment: This occured to me. But the zip is local on my machine and something I'm generating as the output of another rule. Is it recommended to new_http_archive for this?

Comment: In that case no, that wouldn't work. What do you need the contents of this zip for? Could everything just depend on the zip and unzip it into $TMPDIR before executing? We do something similar in our build

Comment: The overall task I'm trying to do is to import a CMake project. So far I've managed to write a genrule to compile the CMake project and create a zip of lib/ and include/, but I can't figure out the next step.

Comment: If you are trying to import an external dependency, then a workspace rule is perfectly reasonable.  I believe using the `file:///` url pattern should work but if it does not, you can write a custom rule that will do the unzipping and call cmake.

Comment: Hmm, maybe? But then am I hard coding some filesystem location into the workspace file?

Comment: Also, calling cmake isn't the tricky part. Passing around the large number of generated .so's and .h's is. That's why I thought of passing it around as a zip.