# How to extract resource from downloaded jar

Tags: bazel

I want to extract some specific resource from jar (which, in turn, is downloaded as a part of http archive) and while I know how to achieve this in principle I don't know what is the most bazelish and minimal way to achieve this.

I've naïvely tried (after reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46326749/how-do-i-unzip-a-file-in-bazel-properly-if-i-dont-know-the-contents-of-the-zip) answer) to do something like this:

```
new_http_archive(
    name="some_jar_contents",
    url="@some_archive//:lib/some_jar.jar",
    build_file_content="""
      filegroup(
          name = "srcs",
          srcs = glob(["*"]),
          visibility = ["//visibility:public"]
      )
    """
)
```

However, I'm predictably getting `java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol:`

Answer (score 3):

The problem you are getting is caused by the fact that Bazel does not understand the url `@some_archive//:lib/some_jar.jar`.
It cannot infer the protocol to use for fetching the Jar, and the exception is thrown.

The rule `new_http_archive` is intended to be used for fetching a compressed archive from certain remote location, then build & expose it as an external target to current repo.

You need to change the `url` parameter to the actual URL in order to let Bazel fetch the Jar with the resource you want to extract.
Then, in `build_file_content` parameter part, use `genrule` to move the desired resource file, and export it.

A working example can be found [in this private gist](https://gist.github.com/izzyleung/df49c388d87e1647638926fc1ca3d79b).

The example does the following things:

- Fetches the Jar for [AutoValue](https://github.com/google/auto/tree/master/value) in `WORKSPACE`
- Uses `genrule` to extract the `autovalue.vm` file from the Jar
- Have a Python Program that reads and prints content of `autovalue.vm`

---

Helpful resources:

- [genrule](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/general.html#genrule)
- ["Make" Variables](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/make-variables.html)
- [Updating the runfiles tree structure](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/wiki/Updating-the-runfiles-tree-structure)